# Accessing table extension in FITS file

Tags: import, list-manipulation, fits-format

I have a FITS file [here](https://mega.nz/#!TVNAwRYZ!hLmFOVuU1leEffEw2HdNI_ZEhXSWwq5AuG0s2zA3EMY) that has no image but simply has a binary table in its extension. I have tried using `Import["file","Tabledata"]` but it returns an empty array.

edit: `Import["file","TableData"]` (still returns empty array) as pointed out by Edmund

Specifically, I'm looking for the Mathematica equivalent of the `astropy` code:

```
import astropy.fits as fits
hdulist = fits.open('file')
tableData = hdulist[1].data (*Reads the table in the first extension*)
```

I want to be able to get `tableData` in Mathematica. How do I achieve this?

Edit: Perhaps I need to be a bit more specific. `astropy` is able to associate headers to columns to a binary table imported from a `FITS` file. Is there way to do that in Mathematica? What I have been able to do so far is separately obtain the data table from `Import["file","Data"]` (thanks to Edmund), and headers from `Import["file","Metadata"]`. Is there a way  to associate these two so that I can call columns using their respective headers?

Comment: The element is `"TableData"` not `"Tabledata"`; *Mathematica* is case-sensitive. In any case, `"TableData"` is empty for this file.  However, it does have something in `"Data"`.  Try `Import["file","Elements"]` to see all the elements it supports.  Supports doesn't mean it will necessarily have data for the particular file you have.

Comment: `"Data"` does seem to import the correct values but it simply stores all numbers. There is no association to table headers like in `astropy`. Is that possible in Mathematica? I mean, is there an inbuilt function to achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to open the file in another application and find what you are looking for.  I ask as perhaps the file does not contain the information you seek.  I suggest opening it in an application that is not the application you used to create it.  That would show whether or not the file as an issue.

Comment: Yes, the file is perfectly fine. I just downloaded this from a particular site. I can access all the data easily using Python. I was just wondering whether there is a neat way to do that in Mathematica. `Import["file","Data"]` works, but it is simply too slow (takes nearly five minutes while Python does it in a jiffy) and it doesn't give the table headers. I need to separately add that to the table.

Comment: It only takes a few seconds to get the `"Data"` element for me.  What version are you using? Is this a FITS file from a workout app with heart-rate and things in it? If it is then *Mathematica*'s FITS file is not of format of FITS.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.0. No, this isn't that FIT format. This is a standard FITS file that contains astrophysical data. Strange, I'll try running it on version 10.4 and report.

Comment: Yes @Edmund, it takes just a few seconds on 10.4. Although I guess it's unfair to compare because my 11.0 is on Windows and 10.4 on Ubuntu (11.0 on Windows has always been sluggish for me).